# I am getting below error in my project while loading Chrome driver : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy

Tags: java, selenium, maven, webdriver, testng

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
FAILED: launch
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.(ClientConfig.java:33)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:95)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:85)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(DriverCommandExecutor.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromeDriver.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:48)
at testcases.AppLuanchTest.launch(AppLuanchTest.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 38 more

Comment: Please follow the stackoverflow formation for posting quesions.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this issue and have solved it by adding `dev.failsafe` to my classpath (in my case, `failsafe-3.3.0.jar`).